# Compartilhar Facebook

Tags: api, facebook

A documentação do facebook é meio falha. Quais parâmetros eu devo passar para compartilhar um produto e sua foto no facebook vindo de um site?

Eu crio o caminho da página:

```
$url = $base_url."index.php/{$controller}/".join('/',$parametros);
```

E coloco como data-href como diz a API:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="<?php echo $url ?>" data-layout="button_count"></div>
```

Comment: Como você está fazendo? Poste o código

Comment: E mesmo assim, sem a imagem não funciona rs.

Comment: Vc possui as meta tags? http://davidwalsh.name/facebook-meta-tags Depois teste aqui: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Answer (score 3):

Você precisa incluir a *meta tag* abaixo no seu *html* para a imagem ser detectada no compartilhamento.

```
<meta property="og:image" content="LINK_DA_IMAGEM"/>
```

Para obter mais informações sobre as *meta tags*, acesse https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ e coloque o *link* da sua página. Irão aparecer outras possíveis *meta tags* que estejam faltando em sua página.

Comment: É, mas só a imagem ele nem precisa incluir porque se a imagem estiver no documento, ele vai pegar de qualquer forma. Mas pra um share perfeito, ele tem que inserir é OPEN GRAPH, e nao somente o meta.............

Answer (score -2):

As propriedades do link nao sao especificadas no botao. No caso vc teria que usar o Js dialog ui.feed que vai poder especificar as informacoes do compartilhamento explicitamente, mas o ideal ai nao é nem uifeed nem share button, basta implementar um like.. Like button..  E colocar propriedades para ser recomendar (nao e um produto??) e ativar o compartilhar. Vai aparecer os dois. Agora quanto a imagem vc tera que implementar o open graph .

Com open graph compartilha através do link, ele e´ propriedade de um URL, se o camarada tem uma página de UM produto é isso que ele tem que fazer mesmo. Mas ele vai ter que implementar o troço completo. Se for uma aplicação ele consegue fazer um dialog de postagem, no caso, fb.ui ou fb.feed nao sei.Aí costumava especificar imagem titulo e sub descrição de um post. Ele pode direcionar pro app, e pode carregar uma variável, podia antes tambem colocar um botao de ação no post feito, e esse botao retornava a variável. Hoje o link deve ter detalhes e ele será um objeto rico tipo produto .
aprende sô, le a  documentação